# General error: 1364 Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, mode, strict

I got a project, which make insertions which inserting no values(not empty values) to the columns with **NOT NULL** and **NO DEFAULT** values. 
I believed that is impossible to make insertion with missing required values, and it always throws an error: Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value. But as I see [here](https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Solution-for-MariaDB-Field--xxx--doesn-t-have-a-default-value-5-2720.html) mysql can be set to

```
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I am confused, cause I think it is dangerous. And if I switch it OFF it will apply to all projects and it could be really bad. So what should I do? Is it possible to set the mode only for one mysql database while other databases will be on STRICT mode? What do you think about it? Is it an issue or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql-mode system variable is available at both global and session level. Which means either you have to set this for entire server or particular connection. So there is no way to configure this for subset of DBs at server level. However you can specify the sql mode when you are making the connection. So those connections will run in strict mode.

Comment: Please refer the details at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: I hope it is also possible to to set session to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.  How it will look like in php?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert. If there is no option at connector you might have to execute "SET SESSION sql_mode = '<mode you want>'" before execute other queries. I assume that you can execute multiple queries using same connection. Hopefully you don't create the connections everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I have it. In PHP/PDO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975351/how-can-i-set-the-sql-mode-while-using-pdo

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i propose is to made a trigger so when there is a no value it will insert a null value to that column

this is an example :

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
             SET NEW.amount = 0;
         END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Project is almost done so is impossible to make triggers for all tables...

Answer (score 0):

So if somebody wants to know how it looks like in PHP/PDO for one concrete session:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
     $dsn, 
     $username, 
     $password, 
     array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"') 
);
```