# Why does PHP PDO ignore NOT NULL constraints?

Tags: php, pdo, null, mariadb, constraints

I'm inserting values into my MariaDB using PDO in PHP. However, when I violate a NOT NULL constraint, nothing happens. I want an Exception to be thrown in that case.

This is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT auto_increment NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(255) NULL,
    lastname varchar(255) NULL,
    telephone varchar(255) NULL,
    alias1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    alias2 varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Here is the PHP script, I use for testing:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tibsi-data', 'root', '',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);

try {
    $stm = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (firstname) VALUES (:firstname)");
    $stm->bindValue(':firstname', 'Mike');

    $success = $stm->execute();
    if (!$success) {
        throw new Exception($stm->errorInfo()[2]);
    }
    $stm->closeCursor();

    $insertId = $conn->lastInsertId();

    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $insertId));
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
} catch (Error $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
}
```

As you can see `alias1` does not have a default value and I omit it in my INSERT statement. I do get an error when I try the same thing using an SQL Script.
I expect this to throw an exception in PHP resulting in a 500 response. Instead, it inserts the row using an empty string for `alias1`. I never set this as a default.
Is there some attribute I can set to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/null-values/

> If a NULL value is single-row inserted into a column declared as `NOT NULL`, an error will be returned. However, if the SQL mode is not
> strict (default until MariaDB 10.2.3), if a NULL value is multi-row
> inserted into a column declared as `NOT NULL`, the implicit default for
> the column type will be inserted (and NOT the default value in the
> table definition). The implicit defaults are an empty string for
> string types, and the zero value for numeric, date and time types.
>
> Since MariaDB 10.2.4, by default both cases will result in an error.

The last statement applies if the `sql_mode` set strict mode. Strict mode is set on by default in MariaDB 10.2.4 and later, but you may have changed that option at the instance or session level. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/

Check your current `sql_mode` in a query client:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

I'm not sure why the documentation refers to multi-row inserts specifically. The same thing happens if you insert a single row and strict mode is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be a strange PDO default. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846103/17183210) to set it in PDO.